# How to pass parameter in Json in data?

Tags: c#, json

I have a text box in aspx page. from that i need to send the text of the textbox in function in Json For that i have a method in server side.

```
   [WebMethod]
    public static OfficeDetails[] BindSearchDatatable(string officename)
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        List<OfficeDetails> details = new List<OfficeDetails>();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=GTL--7\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select  OfficeName,City,Country from Office where OfficeName like '%" + officename + "%'", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                foreach (DataRow dtrow in dt.Rows)
                {
                    OfficeDetails Office = new OfficeDetails();
                    Office.OfficeName = dtrow["OfficeName"].ToString();
                    Office.City = dtrow["City"].ToString();
                    Office.Country = dtrow["Country"].ToString();
                    details.Add(Office);
                }
            }
        }
        return details.ToArray();
    }
```

and in .aspx page I have

```
 $('#btnSearch').click
                            (
                                function () {
                                    var searchtext = $("#txtSearch").val();

                                    alert(searchtext);
                                    $.ajax(
                                                {
                                                    type: "POST",
                                                    url: "Gridview.aspx/BindSearchDatatable",
                                                    data: "{officename : New}",
                                                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                                    dataType: "json",
                                                    async: true,
                                                    cache: false,
                                                    success: function (data) {
                                                        for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                                                            $("#gvDetails").append("<tr><td>" + data.d[i].OfficeName + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].City + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].Country + "</td></tr>");
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    error: function (x, e) {
                                                        alert("The call to the server side failed. " + x.responseText);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            );
                                    return false;
                                }
                            );
```

Now my Question is I send the Parameter in data but i am getting an error The function is running well.I have tested it without parameter so its running well.so i thing some wrong things is going on passing the text value Of textbox in function.

Comment: what's the error?  And also you ***really*** need to think about that inline SQL - have you never heard of [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)?

Comment: Yes I know about sql injection attacks....My just question was how to pass parameter in Json.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are sending an invalid JSON. Replace:

```
data: "{officename : New}"
```

with:

```
data: "{officename : 'New'}"
```

or even better use the `JSON.stringify` method which wil take care of properly encoding the values:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ officename : 'New' })
```

Also please fix your server side script and use parametrized queries because your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks and if you put this code into the wild, you might find yourself one day with a missing database. Oh and you really don't need any DataTables:

```
[WebMethod]
public static OfficeDetails[] BindSearchDatatable(string officename)
{
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=GTL--7\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True"))
    using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT OfficeName, City, Country FROM Office WHERE OfficeName LIKE @officename";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@officename", "%" + officename + "%");
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            var details = new List<OfficeDetails>();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var office = new OfficeDetails();
                office.OfficeName = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("OfficeName"));
                office.City = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("City"));
                office.Country = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Country"));
                details.Add(office);
            }
            return details.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Strange same things i had done before but didnt work but now its work anyway thanxs Darin

Comment: For more information, @Kartik Partel: you can pass your json data to jsonlint.com to check if it's a valid one :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace:
data: "{officename : New}"

with:

data: {officename : 'New'},

Comment: No, this won't work. An ASP.NET PageMethod expects a JSON encoded request.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Ok. Then, this is better (as you have already recommended using) :  `data: JSON.stringify({ officename : 'New' })`